# How to stop windows from opening Zip folders in the explorer view?

Tags: windows-7, zip

I don't want windows to be able to open zip files in the explorer view. How do I go about disabling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an illustrated and detailed guide about your problem:
[Windows 7 - Zip Folders - Enable or Disable Windows Explorer View](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13619-zip-folders-enable-disable-windows-explorer-view.html)

Comment: In case that link ever goes away - the removal for ZIP folders is deletion of the following registry keys: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\CLSID` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.zip\CLSID` and similarly for CAB files.  If you want to re-enable, create those keys again and set their default REG_SZ values to `{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}`; CAB is: `{0CD7A5C0-9F37-11CE-AE65-08002B2E1262}`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that shouldn't break any Windows scripting host/PowerShell functions (as noted in the later pages of the SevenForums link from @Mehper C. Palavuzlar's answer) would be to set a third-party program as the default file handler for ZIP files.

There are several ways to do this below is the easiest to me:

1. Shift+Right-click on a ZIP file and choose `Open with...`
2. Select the program you'd like to use, or click Browse (e.g. to find `C:\Program Files\7-zip\7zFM.exe` for 7-zip).
3. Make sure `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file` is checked.
4. Click OK

Now at least you aren't opening ZIP files in Windows explorer.