# Tool to disable Zip folders in Windows 7 File Explorer

Tags: windows-7, zip

Is there a tool or simple setting to disable Windows 7 Explorer from opening zip folders? There is a registry hack given in [How to stop windows from opening Zip folders in the explorer view?](https://superuser.com/questions/213452/how-to-stop-windows-from-opening-zip-folders-in-the-explorer-view/213454#213454)
but I would rather not hack the registry.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but if you install 7zip and then go to Tools->Options->System you can associate zip files with 7zip and windows will no longer attempt to open them with windows explorer.

Comment: if such a tool exists, it probably updates the registry anyway...

Comment: @dtmland he's talking about Windows 7 built in zip file support, not 7-zip.

Comment: @ultrasawblade - The suggestion is still valid.  You can either disable it through the registry or replace the default behavior with third-party software. Those are the only two options.

Comment: Guess I should have finished reading your comment. :P  7-zip's awesome so that's actually a great idea.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is denies a perfectly answerable duplicate answer. 

Answer (score 2):

Try the steps outlined [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0b064013-fdc2-423d-8426-c714357bd786/how-do-i-disable-zip-folders-in-windows-7):

> For zip files delete the regkey HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}
>
> When you try to delete them, you will almost certainly get an "access
>   denied" or "failed" type of message. Before you can delete them, you
>   need to change the permissions/ownership of these two keys. Here is
>   how to do it:
>
> 01 - open regedit from the RUN console
>
> 02 - navigate to the first key that needs to be deleted
>   (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{E88DCCE0- B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31})
>
> 03 - right click on the key and select "Permissions"
>
> 04 - click on "Advanced"
>
> 05 - click on the "Ownership" tab
>
> 06 - in the "change owner to" section, highlight your username
>
> 07 - check the box for "replace owner on subcontainers and objects"
>
> 08 - click on "Apply"
>
> 09 - Click "OK"
>
> 10 - Under "Security" tab, highlight your username and check the box
>   for "Allow Full Control" (located mid-menu in the "Permissions For
>   Administrators" section)
>
> 11 - click "Apply" and "OK"
>
> 12 - you can now delete the registry key. MAKE SURE YOU ARE ON THE
>   CORRECT KEY!
>
> 13 - repeat the process for the 2nd key.
>
> 14 - reboot (changes will NOT take effect until you reboot
>
> 15 - VOILA! NO MORE ZIP FOLDERS! woohoo!
>
> 16 - thanks to the original solvers of this problem, whomever they may
>   be.

The source talks about de-associating `.cab` files as well, that is why there is the mention about two keys.

Comment: So, nobody knows a tool that does the registry hacks without need for an admin account? And I did not mean to associate zip with a tool, but rather I want to prevent Windows 7 from displaying zips as folders.

Comment: @weberjn any tool that would do this, would just change the registry anyways. Everything about your environment is registry controlled, for the most part.

Comment: @AthomSfere: … but, of course, many aspects of the individual user’s environment are controlled by values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER; the ordinary (non-admin) user can manipulate these.

Comment: @weberjn: … but, of course, many aspects of the individual user’s environment are controlled by values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER; the ordinary (non-admin) user can manipulate these.